# Tutorials GeoJSP API for business intelligence

Tags: postgis, business-intelligence

I need tutorials about **geojsp**. It's an open source component (GPL) written in Java that adds geography to Business Intelligence Systems. I searched for tutorials but I didn't find anything.

Comment: http://www.geojsp.org/ The geojsp website that seems mentioned in a few places online looks a bit dead (it's not in English, but the Google Translated page suggests the domain's been taken over by something weird). Looks like the project might be dead.